# Characterizing the frontier between upward sloping and downward sloping parts of a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let me start with an example, let

$$\mathbf{T}=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&3\end{bmatrix}$$

and $α=(2,2)$. Abusing notation, write $\mathbf{λ}^{α}=(λ^2,(1-λ)^2)$ for any $0≤λ≤1$. If we compute $T^{\top}\mathbf{λ}^{α}$ for every value of $λ$, we obtain a series of points $(x,y)$ that connect $(1,2)$ and $(3,1)$ through a curve. As long as for all $i$, $α_i>1,$ this curve goes through a point in which $x$ is minimum (call it $minX$) and another in which $y$ is minimum ($minY$). In the example, $minX=(\frac{3}{4},\frac{19}{16})$ and $minY=(\frac{13}{9},\frac{2}{3}),$ that correspond to weights $(\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{4})$ and $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}),$ respectively.

I'm only interested in those $\mathbf{λ}$ that yield points between $minX$ and $minY,$ i.e., points that are the result of $\frac{1}{3}\leqλ\leq\frac{3}{4}$. In these points, the slope of the curve (represented in the $x,y$ plane) is negative and $minX$ and $minY$ are the "frontier" points that separate the part in which the curve is negatively sloped from those where it is not. In fact, the slope of the curve at $minX$ is zero and it approaches $\infty$ as we move closer to $minY.$

Similarly, for $n>2$, I'd be interested in those points sitting in the part of curved surface that is "negatively sloped". In $\Bbb R^3$, I want to exclude those portions of the surface for which $x,y$ and $z$ increase simultaneously. Of course, I can still find values for $minX,$ $minY$ and $minZ,$ but I don't know how to determine the rest of the "frontier" points.

**Additional information:** If we define $\mathbf{k}=\mathbf{T}^{\top}\mathbf{\barλ}^{α}$ for any $\mathbf{\barλ}=(\barλ_1,\barλ_2,...,\barλ_n))$, with $\sum_{i=1}^n \barλ_i=1$ and $0\leq \barλ_i \leq 1$, the $\mathbf{λ}$ yielding points between $minX$ and $minY$ have an additional property: they are the ones for which the solution to the problem

$$\max \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i$$
$$s.t. T^{\top}λ^{α}=\mathbf{k},$$

denoted $\mathbf{λ}^*$, is such that $\sum_i \lambda_i^*=1.$ Observe that $\mathbf{\barλ}$ is part of the feasible set, and therefore $\sum_i \lambda_i^*\geq1.$ What I would like is to characterize the $\mathbf{λ}$ that are in the frontier between those resulting in $\sum_i \lambda_i^*=1$ and in $\sum_i \lambda_i^*>1.$

(I'm not sure about the tag, so I apologize if I've misled you and I'd be happy to change it if you can suggest a better one).

Comment: There are some things that need to be cleaned up I think. If $\alpha$ is an ordered pair, then what do you mean by "As long as $\alpha > 1$? Why are you taking the transpose of the symmetric matrix $T$? And lastly, it seems to me that for the example given, the curve is a straight line segment between $(1,3)$ and $(2,1)$.

Comment: @dbx, I meant that each component of $α$ needed to be larger than $1$. I've edited my question and hope it is clearer now. I need to use the transpose because I want to combine columns rather than rows, is just an unhappy coincidence that I've chosen a symmetric matrix. I've corrected also the definition of $λ^{α},$ so it is now the curve it was meant to be. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've been playing around with this very interesting problem, and I don't have a solution -- but I will note that Mathematica *also* doesn't know how to solve it in general.

Comment: @dbx, how did you ask Mathematica?

Comment: I didn't save my code, but it's straightforward to write $T\cdot \lambda^\alpha$ as a system of two nonlinear equations in $\lambda$. Their derivatives are easy enough to find, and finding your frontier points corresponds to finding their critical points. I only tried the Solve[ ] function, which failed.

Comment: @dbx, did you do it for the $\Bbb R^2$ case?

Comment: Yes, the only case I tried was your example.

Comment: Ok @dbx, thank you

Comment: @dbx, I've expanded a bit the question, in case you care to take a second look. Thanks.